Jetpack Compose GoogleMap: MarkerComposable throws exception
I'm working with GoogleMap composable for the first time since I switched from XMLs and ClusterRenderer "oldschool" way.
But I've created ClusterMarker which should display marker pin and size of that cluster as number inside that pin icon.
This is my item:
@Composable
fun BaseClusterMarker(
    size: Int,
    position: LatLng,
) {
    val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = position)

    MarkerComposable(
        state = markerState,
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(
                        width = 40.dp,
                        height = 47.dp,
                    ),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .matchParentSize(),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.map_pin),
                    contentDescription = "",
                )

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.Center),
                    color = MainTheme.colors.main.mapColors.pinTextColor,
                    text = size.toString(),
                    style = MainTheme.typography.text.medium.bold,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                )

            }
        },
    )
}

But for some reason I'm getting
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ComposeView was measured to have a width or height of zero. Make sure that the content has a non-zero size.

How can MarkerComposable throws this exception when Box has fixed size?
Full Map Composable:
@OptIn(MapsComposeExperimentalApi::class)
@Composable
fun BaseGoogleMap(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    defaultPosition: LatLng = Config.GoogleMap.getDefaultPosition(),
    pins: List<MapClusterItem>,
    onPinClick: (MapClusterItem) -> Unit,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(defaultPosition, Config.GoogleMap.DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL)
    }

    val mapStyleOptions = remember {
        loadMapStyleOptions(context, R.raw.custommapstyle)
    }

    val coroutineScope = remember { CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main) }
    
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        uiSettings = MapUiSettings(zoomControlsEnabled = false),
        properties = MapProperties(
            mapStyleOptions = mapStyleOptions,
        ),
    ) {
        Clustering(
            items = pins,
            onClusterClick = { cluster ->
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    cameraPositionState.animate(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            cluster.position,
                            cameraPositionState.position.zoom + 2
                        ),
                        1000
                    )
                }
                true
            },
            onClusterItemClick = { item ->
                onPinClick.invoke(item)
                false
            },
            clusterContent = { cluster ->
                BaseClusterMarker(
                    size = cluster.size,
                    position = cluster.position,
                )
            },
            clusterItemContent = { item ->
                BaseItemMarker(
                    position = item.position,
                )
            },
        )
    }
}

// Helper function to load MapStyleOptions from a JSON file
fun loadMapStyleOptions(context: Context, styleResId: Int): MapStyleOptions? {
    return try {
        val styleJson = context.resources.openRawResource(styleResId).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        MapStyleOptions(styleJson)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null // Return null if there is an issue loading the style
    }
}

Full exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ComposeView was measured to have a width or height of zero. Make sure that the content has a non-zero size.
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.RememberComposeBitmapDescriptorKt.renderComposableToBitmapDescriptor(RememberComposeBitmapDescriptor.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.RememberComposeBitmapDescriptorKt.access$renderComposableToBitmapDescriptor(RememberComposeBitmapDescriptor.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.RememberComposeBitmapDescriptorKt.rememberComposeBitmapDescriptor(RememberComposeBitmapDescriptor.kt:29)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerKt.MarkerComposable-Khg_OnI(Marker.kt:313)
                                                                                                        at com.damidev.ybox24.ui.compose.map.BaseGoogleMapKt.BaseItemMarker(BaseGoogleMap.kt:124)
                                                                                                        at com.damidev.ybox24.ui.compose.map.ComposableSingletons$BaseGoogleMapKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(BaseGoogleMap.kt:100)
                                                                                                        at com.damidev.ybox24.ui.compose.map.ComposableSingletons$BaseGoogleMapKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(BaseGoogleMap.kt:99)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.clustering.ComposeUiClusterRenderer$createAndAddView$view$2.invoke(ClusterRenderer.kt:95)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.clustering.ComposeUiClusterRenderer$createAndAddView$view$2.invoke(ClusterRenderer.kt:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.google.maps.android.compose.clustering.ComposeUiClusterRenderer$InvalidatingComposeView.Content(ClusterRenderer.kt:220)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:259)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:258)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:216)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:132)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:121)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:155)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:154)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:154)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)


Are you sure this exception is coming from MarkerComposable()? It does not feel like that is implemented with a ComposeView().

Yes. Its exact same row as call of this function.

This does not appear to be the whole stack-trace of the exception. Please copy & paste all the red text, so that one maybe can comprehend, what leads up to this ...

added full exception but its issue with ClusterRenderer which is Google function

Issue is that this is happening even for normal marker which is using MarkerComposable.

You haven't included the code in your post, so please check your BaseItemMarker Composable. The stacktrace says there seems to be no size specified in there. You can try to apply a size Modifier, or just remove it altogether to see if that resolves the issue:
Clustering(
    //...
    clusterContent = { cluster ->
        BaseClusterMarker(
            size = cluster.size,
            position = cluster.position,
        )
    },
    // delete clusterItemContent parameter
}


BaseItemMarker is same as that one I posted minus Text. Its fixed Box with Icon in it so far.

Do you still get the error if you remove the ``clusterItemContent` parameter? If yes, what does its stacktrace say now?

Exactly same error for BaseClusterMarker. It works only if I remove both of them and comment them out. Then marker is rendered on map correctly but with default graphics.

@Martin Unfortunately I can't test this myself as I don't have an API key at hand. Please also try to just place a very simple Composable in there, like a simple Text("TEST") and see if it still crashes.

Yeah I've tried just Text but same exception. Even if I put there just Text with Modifier.size(47.dp) it throws exception that it has zero width and height. This might be bug on Google side. It doesnt make sense.
